# Скопировать многомерный массив в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

Необходимо сделать копию массива, которая не будет ссылаться на старый массив. Пробовал с помощью jQuery, но всё равно при изменении нового массива меняются значения в старом.

```
array_1 = $.extend(true, [], array_2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newArray = oldArray.slice();

-------------------------------------------------------------------

function cloneObject(source) {
    for (i in source) {
        if (typeof source[i] == 'source') {
            this[i] = new cloneObject(source[i]);
        }
        else{
            this[i] = source[i];
    }
    }
}
 
var obj1= {bla:'blabla',foo:'foofoo',etc:'etc'};
 
var obj2= new cloneObject(obj1);
```

Answer (score 1):

или так:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3], [[1,2], [1,2], 1], 2];
var newArr = arr.map(function func(el){
    if(Object.prototype.toString.call(el) == "[object Array]"){
        return el.map(func);
    }
    return el;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Помогло такое решение. Отсюда: http://snowcore.net/clone-javascript-object

Большое спасибо Gorets и Spectre.

```
function clone(o) {
    if (!o || ‘object’ !== typeof o) {
        return o;
    }
    varc = ‘
    function’ === typeof o.pop ? [] : {};
    var p, v;
    for (p in o) {
        if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            v = o[p];
            if (v & amp; & amp;‘object’ === typeof v) {
                c[p] = clone(v);
            } else {
                c[p] = v;
            }
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```